# Can not use NVIDIA binary driver from Additional drivers ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Can't activate proprietary driver for NVIDIA from "Additional drivers" Ubuntu 14.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04,64 bit, with NVIDIA GeForce GTX960 dedicated graphics card.

These days I am trying to install NVIDIA driver and always failed, finally I installed it but can not use, please help~

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your manually installed driver is probably causing the problem. The fix will be to uninstall it, reboot which should pick up the nouveau driver, and then the Software & Updates screen you show should offer the Nvidia 375.66 as an active choice.

Locate any line like  "blacklist nouveau" in any file in /etc/modprobe.d  These should all disappear when you uninstall manually your proprietary driver.  Uninstall the driver. Check that no "blacklist nouveau" line is left, if so, delete it or comment it out.
Reboot, and you should have the nouveau driver in use:

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

Now use the Software & Updater to install the Nvidia 375.66, which fixes some artifact problems with earlier 375 drivers.  Reboot and you should be using the nvidia driver (repeat above check).